# Komar mass derivation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, mass, symmetry

The Komar mass, a conserved quantity associated with an asymptotically time-like Killing vector, for stationary spacetime is 
$$M_K=\frac{-1}{8\pi}\int\int\nabla^{\mu}\xi^{\nu}_{(t)}dS_{\mu\nu},$$
using the definition of surfcae element $dS_{\mu\nu}=-2n_{[\mu}k_{\nu]}\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta$, where $n_{\mu}$ and $k_{\nu}$ are TL and SL unit normal vector to closed hypersurface 2-boundary.
$$M_K=\frac{1}{8\pi}\int\int\nabla^{\mu}\xi^{\nu}_{(t)}(n_{\mu}k_{\nu}-n_{\nu}k_{\mu})\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta.$$
Here, $n_{\mu}=-\frac{\delta^{t}_{\mu}}{|g^{tt}|^{1/2}}$ and $k_{\nu}=\frac{\delta^{r}_{\nu}}{|g^{rr}|^{1/2}}$.
And using the definition of Killing vector $\nabla^{\mu}\xi^{\nu}_{(t)}+\nabla^{\nu}\xi^{\mu}_{(t)}=0$.
$$\Rightarrow M_{K}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\int\nabla^{\mu}\xi^{\nu}_{(t)}n_{\mu}k_{\nu}\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta$$
$$=\frac{-1}{4\pi}\int\int\frac{1}{|g^{tt}g^{rr}|^{1/2}}\nabla^{t}\xi^{r}_{(t)}\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta$$
$$M_K=\frac{-1}{4\pi}\int\int\frac{1}{|g^{tt}g^{rr}|^{1/2}}(g^{tt}\Gamma^{r}_{tt}+g^{t\phi}\Gamma^{r}_{\phi t})\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta.$$
**I got the correct answer for Kerr-Newman black hole but with an overall negative sign. Please correct me, where I am getting wrong?**

Secondly, if we do not use the definition of Killing vectors ($\nabla^{\mu}\xi^{\nu}_{(t)}+\nabla^{\nu}\xi^{\mu}_{(t)}=0$), then we get
$$M_K=\frac{1}{8\pi}\int\int\frac{1}{|g^{tt}g^{rr}|^{1/2}}(-\nabla^{t}\xi^{r}_{(t)}+\nabla^{r}\xi^{t}_{(t)})\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta.$$ And using the definition of covariant derivatives, we get
$$M_K=\frac{-1}{8\pi}\int\int\frac{1}{|g^{tt}g^{rr}|^{1/2}}(g^{tt}\Gamma^{r}_{tt}+g^{t\phi}\Gamma^{r}_{\phi t}-g^{rr}\Gamma^{t}_{rt})\sqrt{\sigma}d^2\theta.$$
Which vanishes for Kerr-Newman black hole. 
**Please correct me, what I am missing.**

Comment: What metric signature are you using for the Kerr-Newman metric? (That could potentially explain the overall minus sign.

Comment: I am working with (-,+,+,+) metric sign convention.

Comment: In that case, I believe the formula for the Komar mass should not include the overall minus sign in your first formula. (See e.g. Caroll eq. 6.38)